# Install4J variables unavailable till next button

Tags: java, install4j

I am trying to create a **button** form component that tests the connection without using the next button because it isn't required before continuing to the next screen. However all the variables that are set in the ui dialog are unavailable till I hit the next button. Anyone have experience of how to either access those variables or force them to be available while on the same dialog without pressing next button.

Variable name: smtp.host
When I read the variable by pressing a button it is empty until I click next -> then back and then I click the button it is assigned and it functions properly.

Answer (score 2):

Run this before you use any of the variables and it will work perfectly.

```
//Save the variables from the form before continuing
if(!formEnvironment.saveFormComponents())
{
    Util.logError(context, "Unable to save form components");
}
```